# How to display code as <code>

Tags: javascript

I've created a button with some input fields for the user to enter the background color and text color for the buttons. This works perfectly. However I would then like to display this dynamic code in a code snippet, for people to copy and paste. (the code you see when you view source)

Here is a link to my page:
https://appointuit.com/home/testbutton/

The js is:

```
function check(){
   document.getElementById('buttonOnline').style.background = document.myForm.colorType.value; 

document.getElementById('buttonOnline').style.color = document.myForm.colorTextType.value; 



}  
function code(){

     document.getElementById('snippet').textContent = document.myForm.buttonOnline.innerHTML;

}
```

Comment: I don't really get the question. The page you sent looks broken. Add a code snippet instead http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and add more details on the desired behavior.

Comment: can you give us a fiddle, so you can get better suggesion

Comment: Is only bg color & font color would be dynamically added? rest structure will be static?

Comment: <form name="myForm"><div class="formgroup">
<label class="">Background color:</label>
<input id="colorType" name="name" type="text">
 </div>
 <div class="formgroup">
    <label class="">Text color:</label>
        <input id="colorTextType" name="name" type="text">
        </div>
<div class="formgroup">
<input type="submit" onclick="check(); return false">        </div>
    </form>
<span id="buttonOnline" style="">
   Book Appointment Online
    </span>   
<div class="formgroup">
<input type="submit" value="generate code" onclick="code(); return false">        </div>
    </form>

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. I have used jQuery for syntax.

```
$(document).ready(function(e)
{
//function to be called on click of the button
var generateHTML = function()
{
var bColor = $('#txtBgColor').val();
var fColor = $('#txtFontColor').val();
var dHtml = "<span style='color:"+ fColor +"background:"+bColor+"'>Book   Appointment Online</span>";

$('#dRegion').html("<pre>"+dHtml+"</pre>");
}
})
```

I think the ids used here are self explanatory to you.

Comment: pkhode, how do I call this in the html?

Comment: @Isimo, I have updated snippet & wrapped it with a function. You need to call `generateHTML()` on click of button

Comment: pkhode, thank you for your help so far. I now have it displaying like this: <span style='color:background:'>Book   Appointment Online

It won't put the value for color & background:. I think it has to do with it being in a <pre> but I need this tag to display the html. please any suggestions?

Comment: you may try that, but I guess it has to do with the single/double quotes

Comment: if you find it helpful,please vote & if it really met your requirements, please mark it accpted. thanks